# How do I get contents of selected row using Python and ttkbootstrap's tableview?

Tags: python, tableview, ttkbootstrap

This code works, but I want to print out the contents of selected row.

ttkbootstrap's tableview uses Tkinter's Treeview, which is well documented and I can get the contents of a row when using Treeview.

```
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
from ttkbootstrap.tableview import Tableview
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *

app = ttk.Window()
colors = app.style.colors

def on_tree_select(event):
    print('hello')

coldata = [
    {"text": "LicenseNumber", "stretch": False},
    "CompanyName",
]

rowdata = [
    ('A123', 'IzzyCo'),
    ('A136', 'Kimdee Inc.')
]

dt = Tableview(
    master=app,
    coldata=coldata,
    rowdata=rowdata,
    paginated=True,
    searchable=True,
    bootstyle=PRIMARY,
    stripecolor=(colors.light, None),
)
dt.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES, padx=10, pady=10)
dt.bind_all('<<TreeviewSelect>>', on_tree_select)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a way to trigger a selection event with `<<TreeviewSelect>>`. Displaying the content of the selected row/s however, is rather straightforward.

```
def on_tree_select(_):
    selected_rows = dt.get_rows(selected=True)
    for row in selected_rows:
         print(row.values)
```

However, this only display items of first row (as a list), which is selected by default when the Tableview loads on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Say you had the same issue as me. It is a bit odd to access it.

Here I point to the selected row
row_obj = dv.get_rows(selected=True)

Here I say the first row of the selection and the second value. In this situation, this would be column 2 of the table.

print(row_obj[0].values[1])

Comment: Please don't forget to format code as code e.g. with four spaces indentation and one empty line above and below.