# Unable to .bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>".. to work with TableView to get selected row data

Tags: tkinter, tableview, ttkbootstrap

I am trying to get the row data of the selected row in a ttkbootstrap Tableview, and as with tkinter treeview, I've always just used .bind("<>",my_func) and my_func would proceed in doing the work.

Here is the code I used, and there is no indication the on_tv_select ran when the selecting a row from the Tableview. In that case, I'm not clear on how to obtain the selected row data.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
from ttkbootstrap.tableview import Tableview

def on_tv_select(event):
    print(f".. I was selected")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    colData = [{'text': 'carID', 'stretch': True},
               {'text': 'Make', 'stretch': True},
               {'text': 'Model', 'stretch': True}]
    rowData = [(1,'Make ZZ', 'Model BA'),
               (2,'Make DD', 'Model Ed'),
               (3,'Z Dude','That other')]
    mainWindow = tk.Tk()
    mainWindow.title("POC-Main Window")

    myTableView = Tableview(master=mainWindow,coldata=colData,rowdata=rowData,paginated=True,searchable=True,bootstyle='primary')
    myTableView.pack(fill='both', expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)
    myTableView.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>",on_tv_select)
    mainWindow.mainloop()
```

I did come about this post [How do I get contents of selected row using Python and ttkbootstrap's tableview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77251976/how-do-i-get-contents-of-selected-row-using-python-and-ttkbootstraps-tableview) which showed `bind_all` though binding to all widgets introduces further issues with my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the source code of `Tableview`, it is actually a `ttk.Frame` with a `ttk.Treeview` inside and this internal `Treeview` widget can be referenced by attribute `view`.

So bind the event to this internal treeview instead:

```py
myTableView.view.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", on_tv_select)
```